# Comparing two CSV files and searching for similar items

Tags: python, csv, concatenation

I'm still new to Python and I'm trying to adapt this code to work for me from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268929/python-comparing-two-csv-files-and-searching-for-similar-items).

The difference between that post and what I'm looking for is that I am looking to concatenate the entire contents of the matching rows from both hosts.csv and masterlist.csv when a matching 'signature' is found in both files.

So if hosts.csv looked like this:

```
Path    Filename    Size    Signature
C:\     a.txt       14kb    012345
D:\     b.txt       99kb    678910
C:\     c.txt       44kb    111213
```

And masterlist.csv looked like this:

```
Signature    Name    State
012345       Joe     CT
567890       Sue     MA
111222       Dan     MD
```

Tinkering with the code posted by Martijn Pieters in his response to Serk's post, his code gets me most of the way there.

```
import time, csv
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M")
outputfile = "Results_" + (timestr) + ".csv"

    with open('masterlist.csv', 'rb') as master:
        master_indices = dict((r[0], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(master)))

    with open('hosts.csv', 'rb') as hosts:
        with open('results.csv', 'wb') as results:    
            reader = csv.reader(hosts)
            writer = csv.writer(results)

            writer.writerow(next(reader, []) + ['RESULTS'])

            for row in reader:
                index = master_indices.get(row[3])
                if index is not None:
                    message = 'FOUND in (row {})'.format(index)
                else:
                    message = 'NOT FOUND'
                writer.writerow(row + [message])
```

Instead of just adding the RESULTS column as Serk was looking for that indicates the matching signature, how can I pull in the corresponding rows from the masterlist.csv and hosts.csv files and concatenate the two together in the results.csv file? The desired output file would look like this:

```
Path    Filename    Size    RESULTS          Signature    Name  State    
C:\     a.txt       14kb    FOUND in Row 1   012345       Joe   CT
D:\     b.txt       99kb    FOUND in Row 2   678910       Sue   MA
C:\     c.txt       44kb    NOT FOUND        111213
```

Thanks in advance, responses on here have already help me out with most of the solutions I have been looking for!

Comment: Do you have to use Python? The `join` shell command does this already. (Also, the name of the operation you're doing is "join." It's really common in relational databases.)

Answer (score 3):

Use pandas.read_csv and merge on "Signature" columns

```
import pandas as pd

hosts_df = pd.read_csv("hosts.csv ")
masterlist_df = pd.read_csv("masterlist.csv")
results = masterlist_df.merge(hosts_df, on="Signature", how="outer")
results.to_csv("results.csv")
```