# Comparing 2 csv files against one column with additional condition of matching values in different columns

Tags: python, csv

at first I'd like to let you know, that python is just a tool for me, for a side project that I currently work on. I have nothing to do with programming, I learn everything ad hoc, so I'd really appreciate, if you kept this as simple as possible.

So far I managed to process and write my data into 2 csv files, which look like this:

1. Police.csv:

`gmina,    datetime
1,    2008-01-02 12:00:00
1,    2008-01-02 12:00:00
1,    2008-01-02 16:00:00
1,    2008-01-02 16:00:00
1,    2008-01-06 09:00:00
1,    2008-01-06 15:00:00
1,    2008-01-06 20:00:00
1,    2008-01-06 21:00:00`

'gmina' goes from 1 to 10 with multiple dates

2. meteo.csv:

`station,    datetime,    visibility
12100,    2000-01-09 14:00:00,    900.0
12100,    2000-01-09 15:00:00,    900.0
12100,    2000-01-16 06:00:00,    900.0
12100,    2000-01-16 07:00:00,    600.0
12100,    2000-01-16 08:00:00,    900.0
12100,    2000-01-16 12:00:00,    900.0
12100,    2000-01-16 13:00:00,    600.0`

There are 10 different values for 'station'. Number of rows is different for both csv.

What I want to do now, is to find rows with the exact same date and hour, write them into new csv, but only for pairs of keys and values like: 'gmina': '1' and 'station': '12100'; 'gmina': '2' and 'station': '12105' and so on. I reckon I need a dictionary for that. I found something like this: [Python: Comparing two CSV files and searching for similar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268929/python-comparing-two-csv-files-and-searching-for-similar-items). I need something similar, only with this additional condition of matching values from 'gmina' and 'station'. Could you please give me a hint how to implement this condition in above's code? Or maybe it'd be easier to parse those csv files into dataframes and work with pandas?